# How does GPU help in improving iterative questions?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I am using C++ for solving an k-coupling iterative equations. For 3-coupling case, for example,

```
 f(n+1) = g(n) + 2*h(n) + c;
 g(n+1) = 0.5*f(n+1) - h(n);
 h(n+1) = ( f(n+1)+g(n+1) )/2;
```

where C is constant. In C/C++, the implementation is pretty simple

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
  double c= 0.24;
  long k=0;
  vector<double> f(900000000), g(900000000), h(900000000);

  while (k<10000000)
  {
    f[0] = g[0] = h[0] = rand(); // the initial values of f, g, h are randomly picked
    for (long n=1; n<900000000; n++)
    {
      f[n+1] = g[n] + 2*h[n] + c;
      g[n+1] = 0.5*f[n+1] - h[n];
      h[n+1] = ( f[n+1]+g[n+1] )/2; 
    }
    //if the final value of f, g, h satisfying some condition then record it and go for next iteration 
    if (is_good(f[899999999], g[899999999], h[899999999]))
    {
      // record f[899999999], g[899999999], h[899999999]
      k++;
    }
  }
}
```

This code is pretty slow because it progress slowly and depends on random initial. I didn't program GPU before but I read some introduction and it said GPU is pretty fast for some case. I read few examples and I have a feeling that GPU can only be used for the case which is 'divisible' (I mean the task could be divided into subtask so could be implemented in parallel). I wonder how much will it help for my case. Any idea or suggestion will be highly welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Your program can be easily parallelized on the `while (k<10000000)` loop.  In fact, since the program termination condition is an unknown number of iterations (to reach 10M good sets), you can essentially drop this entire code that you have shown in a kernel and run it as-is, with just a few minor modifications.

```
#include <curand.h>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

__constant__ double c = 0.24;
__device__ volatile unsigned int k = 0;
#define SCALE 32767.0
#define NUM_GOOD 10000000

__device__ int is_good(double f, double g, double h){
  if (....){
    ...
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

__global__ void initCurand(curandState *state, unsigned long seed){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x*blockDim.x;
  curand_init(seed, idx, 0, &state[idx]);
}

__global__ void mykernel(curandState *devStates, double *good_f, double *good_g, double *good_h){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
  double f0, g0, h0, f1, g1, h1;
  curandState localState = devStates[idx];
  while (k<NUM_GOOD){
    // assuming you wanted independent starting values for f, g, h
    f0 = (double)(curand_uniform(&localState)*SCALE);
    g0 = (double)(curand_uniform(&localState)*SCALE);
    h0 = (double)(curand_uniform(&localState)*SCALE);
    for (int i = 0; i< 450000000; i++){
      f1 = g0 + 2*h0 + c;
      g1 = 0.5*f1 - h0;
      h1 = (f1+g1 )/2;
      f0 = g1 + 2*h1 + c;
      g0 = 0.5*f0 - h1;
      h0 = (f0+g0 )/2;}
    if (is_good(f1, g1, h1))
    {
      unsigned int next =  atomicAdd(&k, 1);
      if (next<NUM_GOOD){
        good_f[next] = f1;
        good_g[next] = g1;
        good_h[next] = h1;}
    }
  }
}
```

The above code is just an outline, there may be some errors and obviously not everything is defined here.

You can play with the number of actual threads that you launch to see what runs the fastest.  All of the threads launched will work on filling the "good" stack, until it is filled.  Then each thread will detect that the stack is full and exit.

**EDIT:** responding to some questions below:

> it seems that "int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;" is GPU stuff, I think it is related to the threading in GPU, so is it critical to GPU programming?

Yes, these variables like `threadIdx.x` are "built-in" variables in CUDA which allow each thread to do something different (start with different random values, in this case).

> Secondly, all the code you gave looks like a regular C++ code. But you put "GPU critical section", so is that any special syntax I need to use in that section or it is just like the regular c++ code?

Yes, much of CUDA kernel code can be ordinary C++ code, frequently similar to what you might write to do the same thing on the CPU.  In this case I mentioned a critical section and had linked an example, but after thinking about it, a critical section (in this case used to limit access to a data area so that GPU threads don't step on each other as they are updating "good" values) is overkill here.  It's only necessary to use an [atomic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) operation to reserve a "spot" in the stack for each thread that wants to populate a good value.  I have modified the code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code has something new to me. I have two questions: it seems that "int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;" is GPU stuff, I think it is related to the threading in GPU, so is it critical to GPU programming? Secondly, all the code you gave looks like a regular C++ code. But you put "GPU critical section", so is that any special syntax I need to use in that section or it is just like the regular c++ code? Thanks again.

Comment: I responded to your questions in my answer and also edited/updated the code slightly to simplify the "critical section" to just an atomic operation.

Answer (score 1):

According to

```
 while (k<10000000)
```

you are trying to find 10M good `{f, h, g}`.

In your single-thread CPU code, you are finding them one by one, while in GPU, it is easy to launch thousands of threads to find the satisfied results in parallel, until the total number reaches 10M.

For the coupling iterative part, you still need to compute them in the traditional way. But you still be able to improve the performance on this part by simplifying the equations as

```
f(n+1) = 1   *g(n) + 2*h(n) +      c;
g(n+1) = 0.5 *g(n)          +  0.5*c;
h(n+1) = 0.75*g(n) + 1*h(n) + 0.75*c;
```

The transformation matrix `A` for vector `[f,g,h,c]'` is (in matlab code)

```
A = [ 0 1 2 1 ; 0 .5 0 .5; 0 .75 1 .75 ; 0 0 0 0];
```

Then we have `[f,g,h,c]'{n}=A^n * [f,g,h,c]'{0}`. You will find `A^n` converge to `[0 3 2 3; 0 0 0 0; 0 1.5 1 1.5; 0 0 0 0]` in a few iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I used openmp before but it seems that GPU programming is not the same thing. I read some materials about CUDA. If I create the array in GPU, can I simply use exactly same code as shown above so to run in GPU?

Comment: OpenACC is similar to OpenMP. It can parallel your existing C/C++ code to run on GPU. But for best performance, you may need to write the CUDA code.